# Aspnet Boilerplate 2-factor authentication

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Aspnet Boilerplate to manage a multi-tenant system.  I am currently attempting to turn on 2-factor authentication, which is baked into the boilerplate.  I have logged into the host and turned on 2FA (because I understand that it can't be on in the tenanats unless it's on in the host first).
[Host 2-factor settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrOdc.png)
Once I do this, I can now see the settings to turn 2FA on in each tenant (which I have).  My problem is that, while the host users are indeed asked for a code as expected, no tenant users ever are.  This line of code:

```
var signInResult = await _signInManager.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(loginResult, loginModel.RememberMe);
```

never returns `RequiresTwoFactor == true` for tenant users.  I can't dig into that that call, so I don't know exactly what's happening, but I'm wondering if someone can tell me something I'm missing about turning on 2FA for tenants.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I've been able to narrow down the issue to the fact that, within that function mentioned in my original post, it calls `GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync` -- which then returns an empty list.  This is what is causing the call to assume that 2FA is not necessary.  I think I will ask why this is happening in a separate question, as to not befuddle this question with a digression.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this resolved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709499/aspnet-boilerplate-getvalidtwofactorprovidersasync-returns-an-empty-list?

Comment: Yes, this is resolved.  I was unaware of the IsEmailConfirmed and IsPhoneNumberConfirmed flags in the database.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aspnet Boilerplate GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync returns an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709499/aspnet-boilerplate-getvalidtwofactorprovidersasync-returns-an-empty-list)